# Convert that had children prior to conversion

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, conversion-to-judaism, children-parenting

If a fellow converted (his children remained gentiles) and prior to his conversion he had children - has he fulfilled the Mitzva of Peru U'Revu? (sources)

Comment: I think you need to distinguish between "fulfilling the mitzvah", and subsequently being "exempt from the mitzvah". See the tshuva of Har Tzvi (OH 2:76).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is part of a discussion on [Yevamot 62a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=14&daf=62&format=pdf). The Shulchan Aruch rules (EH 1:7) that if he and his children converted he has fulfilled his mitzva. The Chelkat Mechokek there (sk 9) quotes the Marharil (#223) that even if his children do not convert he has fulfilled his mitzva.

Comment: And the Taz there says the opposite, that the children must convert also.

Comment: @Curiouser Just like the Shulchan Aruch himself, and the Rambam and others. I was just quoting one major opinion on both sides. Obviously CYLOR.