# Is it possible for a man to convert to Judaism without circumcision?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, brit-milah

Is it possible for a man to convert to Judaism without circumcision?

I'm not talking about where [medical reasons](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33388/what-happens-when-a-potential-convert-cant-have-a-circumcision) would prevent circumcision; I'm curious to know if an uncircumcised gentile can convert to Judaism without going through circumcision -- a man who doesn't want to get a circumcision, but is otherwise capable of doing so without medical risk.

Comment: Do you mean to ask if a man can convert to Judaism even if he doesn't want to get a circumcision, but is otherwise capable of doing so without medical risk? Or are you asking about someone already circumcised? The question linked isn't clear either

Comment: Why doesn't he want to?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Interesting question.

Comment: I think that there are (a very few but) some Reform rabbis who do not require circumcision. There may be Renewal rabbis in that category, and perhaps Reconstructionist, but I think the vast _VAST_ majority are not.

Comment: Kasper -- you're right, no one should take out relevant parts of a question _for no reason_. However, once people have answered the question, it's not fair to invalidate their answers by changing a question (see [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1231/5323) for more info.) If you would like to [ask a new question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) that's fine. [ cc @msh210 ]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Circumcision is one of the Torah's 613 commandments  (#86 of the [רמב"ם's list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/613_commandments#Maimonides.27_list); [בראשית יז:י](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0117.htm#10)).  A convert to Judaism has to accept all of them.  If he does not accept even one of those commandments, he is not accepting Judaism, and has not converted.

If he accepts that is a valid commandment but doesn't wish to fulfill it, he might as well not convert, so that he won't get punished for that.

Comment: " A convert to Judaism has to accept all of them. If he does not accept even one of those commandments, he is not accepting Judaism, and has not converted." source?

Comment: "If he accepts that is a valid commandment but doesn't wish to fulfill it, he might as well not convert, so that he won't get punished for that." so are you saying that the conversion would be valid then, just useless?

Comment: Where is there a discussion about the (im)possibility of a man converting to Judaism without accepting the Oral Torah?

Comment: Not sure about the accuracy of this answer. While converts must accept the yoke of mitzvos (and it isn't unanimously accepted that this is requirement can invalidate a conversion), the circumcision of conversion has a much more primary role for men.

Answer (score 10):

In order to convert one has to accept all the commandments, which includes circumcision. If one would clearly not want to accept one of the commandments no Orthodox Rabbi would do such a conversion.

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_12136_14.pdf

Comment: but isn't circumcision part of the conversion process, not just one of the mitzvot that a convert must agree to accept?

Comment: But suppose he accepts the command of _b'ris_ but says either (a) I'll do it next week, I just don't wanna now, or (b) I accept the command but it's just too hard for me, I can't bring myself to.

Comment: @msh210: Suppose a potential convert says I accept the command of Shabbos, however I want to (a) wait another week, I just don't wanna now, or (b) I accept the command but it is too hard for me, I can't bring myself to - would any Bais Din accept such a conversion?

Comment: @GershonGold, I dunno, could be.

Comment: @msh210: I disagree obviously. I would be willing to delete my answer if you prove me wrong.

Comment: I agree you're mostly likely right, but haven't proven it. (Unless the _Hapardes_ link proves it. I haven't checked.)

Comment: Can you update the answer to specify which commandments exactly? "all the commandments, which includes" is too vague to accept as an answer.

Comment: I am not sure what is vague about all the commandments. All=All

Comment: Where is there a discussion about the (im)possibility of a man converting to Judaism without accepting the Oral Torah?

Answer (score 5):

As Shalom [alluded](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/33392/440) to there are two ways to evaluate circumcision vis-a-vis a Ger. One is that it is part of the **process** of becoming Jewish (for a man). In that case, there is really nothing to start with - if he isn't getting a circumcision it isn't doing the process, he doesn't become Jewish.

However, in the case where he can't have a circumcision, there are two possible cases. One is that he lacks the anatomy (there could have been a previous accident, etc.). In that case he is viewed as it is with a woman - it doesn't apply to him. However, if he has the technical capacity to have circumcision, but could not **with permission** of the Torah - i.e. the procedure would kill him, or there is a substantial concern of that outcome - then he simply cannot convert. It is not that he can become Jewish and skip the circumcision. He can't fulfill the circumcision according to the Torah, so he can't become Jewish according to the Torah. (Or perhaps he can choose to risk his life according to the Torah in this case).

The second way of evaluating it is that the requirement of circumcision is a technical point - he is becoming Jewish, so he is required to be circumcised. He takes care of that first so he doesn't spend any time as a Jew without fulfilling that obligation. In that case, if the procedure has a substantial concern of killing him, the Torah says that he is **exempt** from this commandment, at which point the conversion can proceed without it. (There is another way of looking at this - if the Torah says he is exempt he can convert, just like he can convert without bringing the sacrifice since we don't have the Temple today and he is thus exempt from the sacrifice but can still convert - but in that case conversion without actually being exempt from circumcision is a non-starter just like the first evaluation).

In the case of someone who simply doesn't want to have a circumcision, according to the first evaluation above - there is nothing to talk about. According to the second evaluation, it would get into a different discussion. One of the fundamental requirements of conversion is accepting the obligations of the Torah. If someone is rejecting any of it, the conversion is not valid. So if someone doesn't agree to be circumcised, he is rejecting a Mitzvah and would thus invalidate any conversion ceremonies. Note that it isn't enough to agree that in theory G-d commanded them. The convert actually has to intend to do them. Here the refusal is clearly showing that he has no such intention.

There is an edge case to discuss here - he converts not knowing that he has to be circumcised. Because while the convert has to accept upon himself to do all of the commandments, he doesn't have to actually know what they all are. According to the second evaluation, he might well end up being Jewish. That would be a shame, because while as a non-Jew he could have had a share in the world to come, as an uncircumcised Jew (at least as the Rambam defines Kares) he would not.

As for which commandment - there is a constant obligation for a Jewish male to be circumcised from 8 days on ([Vayikra 12:3](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9913#v=3&showrashi=true)). See what I wrote about that [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33812/does-a-mitzvah-fulfilled-before-one-is-obligated-count/38699#38699).

Comment: Interesting ideas here....have any sources (soundsn like it would be _sifrei acharonim_) to back these up?

Comment: @Shokhet, I don't have time to look up and recall the various sources involved, but for example, the [דבר אברהם](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14444&st=&pgnum=132&hilite=) is very clear that it is part of the process (the first side of the Chakira above).

Comment: No rush; if/when you find the time....btw this is a pretty well-written answer; a yeshivish chakira written clearly, completely in English is pretty rare ;)